# Find base of Ker(f*(2a* + a*))

Tags: linear-algebra

Given: $ f:Q^3 \to Q^2$ linear, with a coordinate matrix A:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Where the bases are: $\{ (1,1,1) , (1,1,0) , (1,0,0) \}$ and $\{a_1,a_2\}$

**Find a base of $Ker(f^*(2a_1^* + a_2^*  )$**

So I'm not sure about what is asked here, isn't $f^*$(*something*) part of the bidual space and therefore a vector? How do I find $a_1^*$ and $a_2^*$?